# SparkSql Json error

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

SparkSql.

Im trying to read a json file > create a TempTable > make a simple Query > and save as text the result.

I get the error that i paste below the Json file.
I'm new on Spark so please explain as much you can. I probably made some mistake.

This is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object testSql {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("sparkSql")
      .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val hiveCtx = new HiveContext(sc)
    val input = hiveCtx.jsonFile("tweet.json")
    input.registerTempTable("tweets")
    val title = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT title FROM tweets")
    title.saveAsTextFile("twt.json")
  }
}
```

This is the twt.json

```
    {
        "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/11/05 17:21:17 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
15/11/05 17:21:18 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/11/05 17:21:18 WARN Utils: Your hostname, daniele-S551LB resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.113 instead (on interface wlan0)
15/11/05 17:21:18 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: daniele
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: daniele
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(daniele); users with modify permissions: Set(daniele)
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.113:43893]
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 43893.
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-f7dac555-9371-442e-8f7c-fbc21bce9978/blockmgr-90f16880-f62c-4fb1-9ee6-5c8d269ed651
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 944.7 MB
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-f7dac555-9371-442e-8f7c-fbc21bce9978/httpd-7702cb01-9ac0-49cc-ad02-86ceb05623e5
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 51255.
15/11/05 17:21:18 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.113:4040
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 56196.
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 56196
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:56196 with 944.7 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 56196)
15/11/05 17:21:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(106480) called with curMem=0, maxMem=990621204
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 104.0 KB, free 944.6 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(10090) called with curMem=106480, maxMem=990621204
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 9.9 KB, free 944.6 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:56196 (size: 9.9 KB, free: 944.7 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from jsonFile at testSql.scala:15
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: jsonFile at testSql.scala:15
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (jsonFile at testSql.scala:15) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(jsonFile at testSql.scala:15)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at jsonFile at testSql.scala:15), which has no missing parents
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3552) called with curMem=116570, maxMem=990621204
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 944.6 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2002) called with curMem=120122, maxMem=990621204
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2002.0 B, free 944.6 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:56196 (size: 2002.0 B, free: 944.7 MB)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:874
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at jsonFile at testSql.scala:15)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1421 bytes)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/daniele/workspace/sparkSql/tweet.json:0+583
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
15/11/05 17:21:20 INFO deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
15/11/05 17:21:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
scala.MatchError: glossary (of class java.lang.String)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:303)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/11/05 17:21:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): scala.MatchError: glossary (of class java.lang.String)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:303)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/11/05 17:21:21 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (jsonFile at testSql.scala:15) failed in 0,683 s
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: jsonFile at testSql.scala:15, took 0,792765 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): scala.MatchError: glossary (of class java.lang.String)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:303)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1801)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.113:4040
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO Utils: path = /tmp/spark-f7dac555-9371-442e-8f7c-fbc21bce9978/blockmgr-90f16880-f62c-4fb1-9ee6-5c8d269ed651, already present as root for deletion.
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
15/11/05 17:21:21 INFO Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f7dac555-9371-442e-8f7c-fbc21bce9978
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a Json file with a specific format with Spark Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702167/how-to-read-a-json-file-with-a-specific-format-with-spark-scala)

Comment: You cannot read multi-line JSON  `SqlContext.jsonFile`. It expects a single document per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to explain here. `SqlContext.jsonFile` expects a single document per line. It cannot read documents spanning over multiple lines or parse lists of documents as rows. Assuming only a single document a correct input would like this:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("""{"glossary": {"GlossDiv": {"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"GlossDef": {"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"], "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."}, "GlossSee": "markup", "Acronym": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "SortAs": "SGML", "ID": "SGML"}}, "title": "S"}, "title": "example glossary"}}"""))

val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- glossary: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- GlossDiv: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- GlossList: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- GlossEntry: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- Abbrev: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- Acronym: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- GlossDef: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSeeAlso: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |    |-- para: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSee: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- GlossTerm: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- SortAs: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

So you simply have to preprocess your data before it can be used to create a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
So there is no way to process json  data until they are formatted in one line?

Comment: If you ask about direct conversion to DataFrame then the answer is no. Otherwise It kind of depends on a context. You use custom Hadoop input format, you can parse data by partition. You can tinker with record separators.